# How to query belongsToMany with OR operator

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I query the data below using Eloquent?

'BelongsToMany' relationships exist between the user model and the team model.

is it possible to initiate a query from both the team and user models?

```sql
SELECT * FROM teams t WHERE
  owner_id = '{auth_id}'
  OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM team_user WHERE team_id = t.id AND user_id = '{auth_id}')
```

Comment: you can use join/leftjoin method if you use laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query in eloquent is something like this:

```php
Team::whereId('your_team_id')
    ->orWhereHas('users', fn ($query) => $query->whereId('your_user_id'))
```

I guess this should work!

Comment: whereHas() is a good idea. Thanks. But, whereId() doesn't work. `where('users.id', ...)` works.

Comment: `Team::where('owner_id', auth()->id())->orWhereHas('users', function ($query) { $query->where('users.id', auth()->id()); })`